# Multiple values for same variable when designing Objects (use of self in Python)

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x, self

I'm new to python (not new to programming), and I've been messing around with the idea of 'self'. I was making great strides, but then I found something interesting with messing around with a small program I made. I created an object called Person. Here's the code of my entire program.

```
class Person():
    name = "temp"
    def __init__(self, aname):
        global name
        print("A Person is created!")
        name=aname
        self.test()

    def test(self):
        print(name)
        print(self.name)

p1 = Person("Tim")
```

As you can see, I create a variable called 'name'. In the constructor, I pass in a variable called 'aname' and assign it to the variable 'name'. At the end of the constructor, I call a method called test which prints out two things. The first actually prints what I set name to in the constructor (in this case, "Tim", as you can see by the last line of the code) but the second prints "temp", which is what I initialize 'name' to. Shouldn't the values be the same? What's the difference between using and not using self in my scenario?

Just for reference, here's what is printed out,

> A Person is created!
>
> Tim
>
> temp

Comment: The difference will become apparent when you instantiate more than one `Person`. You'll find that they share the same `name` — that is, modifying one `Person` is the same as modifying all of them. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: But why does 'name' point to the value that was changed to 'Tim'? And why does 'self.name' go to "temp"? The values should be the same.

Comment: @WaleedKhan's answer, while accurately describing what will happen when you create multiple `Person` objects, is technically incorrect.  The `name` which is set to Tim is not the `name` which you initially assign to `"temp"` -- they belong in two different namespaces and scopes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `name` variable which you assign `aname` to in `init` is actually not the same one you initially declare as `tmp` -- it's a whole new global variable.  For example, you can add `print name` at the end of your code:

```
class Person():
    name = "temp"
    def __init__(self, aname):
        global name
        print("A Person is created!")
        name=aname
        self.test()

    def test(self):
        print(name)
        print(self.name)

p1 = Person("Tim")
print name
```

And your output will be:

```
A Person is created!
Tim
temp
Tim
```

Another way to illustrate this is to change the name of the variable altogether:

```
class Person():
    name = "temp"
    def __init__(self, aname):
        global asd
        print("A Person is created!")
        asd=aname
        self.test()

    def test(self):
        print(asd)
        print(self.name)

p1 = Person("Tim")
```

Will also print:

```
A Person is created!
Tim
temp
```

To accomplish what I assume you wish to accomplish -- which is to have a `name` property assigned to each person, use `self.name` to set the property.

```
class Person():
    name = "temp"
    def __init__(self, aname):
        print("A Person is created!")
        self.name=aname
        self.test()

    def test(self):
        print(self.name)

p1 = Person("Tim")
```

(Note that trying to `print(name)` in `test()` will fail, because there is no in-scope property with that name.)

Comment: I'm coming from java, so this may explain my following confusion. I guess what confuses me is the fact that in test(), 'name' is called, which SHOULD point to the initial name initialized with "temp". Does 'name' suddenly become a global variable when calling it in the constructor? Because the fact that you could call it after declaring 'p1' is really confusing.

Comment: @gnasr: You cannot implicitly refer to instance variables like that in Python.  If you want the object attribute, you need to use `self.name`, always.  If you just use `name`, it can only refer to a local or global variable, never to an attribute of the object.

Comment: @BrenBarn: So does that mean I created I global variable when I wrote "name=aname".

Comment: @gnasr: Yes, because you declared `global name`, just like jmduke explains in his answer.  (If you had not written `global name`, then you would have just created a local variable called `name`, which would disappear after `__init__` was done.)

Comment: @gnasr -- you are correct in that this behavior is different than Java.  In Java, the `self.` usage in classes is largely optional:  it's only needed when you pass a parameter to a constructor with the same name as a class property -- otherwise, it's optional.  In Python, this is not true: you must refer to a property of an object with `self`.